# Setting REQUEST header Http Client vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Consider the following VB code:

```
Public Async Function someFunction(ByVal url As String, Optional ByVal methodPost As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal postContent As HttpContent = Nothing) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Using client = New HttpClient
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = makeAuthenticationHeader()

        If methodPost Then
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

            Dim Response = Await client.PostAsync(url, postContent)

            Dim content As String = Await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
            Return content
        Else
            Return Await client.GetStringAsync(url)
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

I want to set the **request** content type to `application/json` as well as the **response** content type to `application/json`.

If I add the following line of code:
`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("content-type", "application/json")` then the system throws an exception `Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.`.

I've searched all over google for a way to set the requests header to JSON. Using fiddler (on the server) I can see that the request is sent as plain/text.

```
POST **URL REMOVED FOR SAFETY REASONS** HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic **HASHED AUTH DETAILS - REMOVED FOR SAFETY REASONS**
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: **HOST REMOVED FOR SAFETY REASONS**
Content-Length: 1532
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` This is where I am having an issue. This needs to be set to a content type for JSON as the body of the request is JSON. How do I set this `content-type` to JSON in vb.net Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I don't know if it is the correct solution or if there is a better solution out there.

Basically you need to set the `content-type` header on the actual content that you are sending and not on the HTTP Client.

So basically adding `content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")` to your code should set the **REQUEST's** content-type to JSON as well.

```
Public Async Function someDifferentFunction() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Dim url As String = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Dim content As HttpContent = New StringContent(txtRequestBody.Text)
    content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
    Return Await someFunction(url, True, content)
End Function
```

Comment: You can also use this Dim content = New StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")